# Is there any multiple template/extension single install pack for Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

Is there any way to install template/plugin/module in one pack. There are many options to install extensions/plugins/modules
http://jeffchannell.com/Joomla/install-multiple-joomla-extensions-in-a-single-package.html
http://digitalvariants.blogspot.com/2011/01/installing-multiple-joomla.html

as single install  but simply none and no way to do this when installing a Joomla! template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla 1.6+ support packages which allow you to combine several zip's for extensions etc into a single zip package.

See: http://docs.joomla.org/Package

Comment: I dont know how to thank you!  I googled 2 days now , have a dev "create" installer  and than I fund out he stole it from someone, browsed docs so many times , THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Akeeba backup.

Akeeba packages everything in your site -- articles, categories, plugins, modules, menus, database, templates, etc.  It generates an installable ZIP file.  This file can be used to re-install your entire site if you needed to.  But I also use it to create "base" installations of Joomla.

Your procedure would be like this:

1. Create a base Joomla installation
2. Install all the extensions you want (including Akeeba)
3. Create a backup ZIP
4. Unpack the ZIP on your server (or upload via ftp)
5. Go through installation procedure just like a "native" Joomla installation

Look here: https://www.akeebabackup.com/software/akeeba-backup.html

Thanks,
Matthew

Comment: The question is about packaging templates and extension in a single file for installation on Joomla sites, not an entire Joomla installation.

Comment: It appears you don't understand Joomla very well.  Nor doid you read the question.  The question is about packaging multiple templates, extensions, and modules in a single install. That's more than just packaging templates and extensions.  The answer I gave accomplishes what the person asked for in a very simple manner, plus gives them the ability to re-package and protect their site.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean - Benn's comment on the answer I provided seem's to imply I answered it to his satisfaction. Your question creates an Akeeba backup that includes the entire Joomla! installation which would replace any existing installation.
As to knowing Joomla, it's true I've only been writing extension for Joomla and building websites in it for 5 years, so you may be right.